# Won't listen to my if statement?

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/C9bQZ/4/

As you can see in the code in JSFiddle, for some reason it is not listening to my if statement?

It is supposed to append the value as a list item if the values length is greater than zero.

Also, how would I go about making these changes real? Would I send them into a JSON formatted file or something, and then call upon that every time I want my actual page displayed? Probably am gonna have to make a whole app with backbone for that, huh?

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
    if(myListItem.length > 0){
```

instead of

```
    if($(myListItem).length > 0){
```

because myListItem is a string, not a DOM element.

In order for the changes to persist, you need to send list values to your application with a $.post, or something to that effect. Then you would save that by whichever means is appropriate.

Comment: I did have it like that at first. I'll give it a go again.

Comment: Thank you sir. Question, when I append it to ul.mylist, does that get inserted into those ul tags? Because if you look at my code again, you see if I click on an LI within my ul.mylist it should be removed. But for each new one that I insert, I am unable to remove them?

Comment: yes, because the list is empty when you create that event handler.  you should add the click event after creating the <li>. see http://jsfiddle.net/C9bQZ/12/

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
if($(myListItem).length > 0){
```

to:

```
if (myListItem.length > 0) {
```

You are trying to make a jQuery object from a string.

http://jsfiddle.net/C9bQZ/6/

Comment: This is so weird.. I had it the way on the bottom, but it began to look wrong so i changed it to the way on top. Either way, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved http://jsfiddle.net/C9bQZ/9/

```
if(myListItem.length > 0){
```

instead of

```
if($(myListItem).length > 0){
```

Its a string not jQuery object.

**EDIT**

Removed the text "You have no list in the list" while adding the list item.

Comment: Please post what you did and not just a link, especially in the case of jsFiddle being down.